Is Box dipole reduction with amorphous structure translation wrong?
I was studying amorphous carbon structures in a quantum mechanics/classical mechanics (QM/CM) approach. To model the interaction of the QM region on the CM region I need to obtain the dipole moment of the QM region. To avoid finite size effects of the QM region, I choose to obtain the ground state of the QM region by including interactions from identical neighboring images up to a cut-off radii.
The number of images required to achieve convergence was proportional to the box dipole at the center of the cell. I was able to reduce the box dipole by moving the amorphous structure around (say in the x direction) while imposing periodic boundary conditions. This would be due to the electron distribution in my case acquiring a more symmetric shape when observed from the center of the cell. This reduced the total number of images required for convergence.
So this result seemed fascinating to me but am I doing something really stupid here? Im new to these QM/CM calculations and mutlipoles, so I could add more information if its requested in the comments.
Thank you.

+1 but I recommend spitting it into paragraphs.
